# Finding the smallest positive x,y such that $x^2 - 17y^2 = 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

Part (b) of this question:

a) Express $\sqrt{17}$ as a continued fraction.

b) Hence, or otherwise, find the smallest positive integers $x$,$y$ such that $x^2 - 17y^2 = 1$.

I'm fine with part (a) and I know that the answer to (b) is probably $x =33$ and $y = 8$ and that it has something to do with the convergents of the continued fraction I found in (a). But I don't really know the relation between $x$, $y$ and these convergents and as a result can't really provide an adequate answer to the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is a Pell’s equation. You can check this (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What did you get for part (a)?

Comment: I got $[4; \bar{8}]$

Comment: You can check your work at http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/cfCALC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The continued fraction for $\sqrt{17}$ is indeed $[4; \bar{8}]$
2. From 1, the convergents are:
   $$
   4 = \dfrac{4}{1}
   ,\qquad
   4 + \dfrac{1}{8} = \dfrac{33}{8}
   ,\qquad
   4 + \dfrac{1}{8+\dfrac{1}{8}} = \dfrac{268}{65}
   $$
   Since $x^2 - 17y^2 = -1$ for $(x,y)=(4,1)$, you need the even-numbered convergents and so $(x,y)=(33,8)$ is the smallest solution of $x^2 - 17y^2 = 1$. The next one is $(x,y)=(2177,528)$.